# Flask SQLAlchemy - how to organize the db Models

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

To create new tables in the db I write something like this:

```
class Cat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    age = db.Column(db.String(40))
    born_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    is_feline = db.Column(db.Boolean)

class Dog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    age = db.Column(db.String(40))
    born_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    wave_tail = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

With only 2 tables created. Cat and Dog. Classic one, from tutorials.

**I want do to something like this**

```
class Animal(object):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    age = db.Column(db.String(40))
    born_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    common_functions

class Cat extends Animal:
      is_feline = db.Column(db.Boolean)

      def override common_functions
      def specific functions

class Dog extends Animal:
      wave_tail = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

with only 2 tables created. Cat and Dog.

Or is there a place where I can learn this. The SQLAlchemy documentation is huge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit your entities from SQLAlchemy Model class and the parent class at the same time:

```
class Animal(object):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    age = db.Column(db.String(40))
    born_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def hi(self):
        print 'hello!'


class Cat(Animal, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cats'
    is_feline = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def hi(self):
        print 'cat'

    def hello(self):
        print 'hello'


class Dog(Animal, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'dogs'
    wave_tail = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```